# 素因数分解を約数にする。ループ,組み合わせの方法を教えて下さい。

Tags: python, アルゴリズム, sympy

問題点①　素因数分解の個数が3個の場合しか対応していません。
問題点②　リスト内包表記の使い方がわかりませんでした。関数部分1行で書けますか。
問題点③　( . [ . { 。使い方、変換についての、おすすめのページを教えて下さい。
よろしくお願いします。

```
from sympy import *
import itertools
var('My_Yakusu')
def My_SoinsuToYakuSu(My_factorint):
    k_list = list(My_factorint.keys())
    v_list = list(My_factorint.values())
    My_list=list(itertools.product(
                 list(range(v_list[0]+1)),
                 list(range(v_list[1]+1)),
                 list(range(v_list[2]+1))))
    My_Yakusu = []
    for i in range(len(My_list)):
        My_Yakusu.append(  k_list[0] ** My_list[i][0] \
                         * k_list[1] ** My_list[i][1] \
                         * k_list[2] ** My_list[i][2] )
    return sorted(My_Yakusu)

print("#sy 90-約数     ",divisors(90, generator=False))
print("#sy 90-素因数分解",factorint(90))
print("#my 90-約数     ",My_SoinsuToYakuSu(factorint(90)))
print("")
print("#630は、間違っています。")
print("#sy630-約数     ",divisors(630, generator=False))
print("#sy630-素因数分解",factorint(630))
print("#my630-約数     ",My_SoinsuToYakuSu(factorint(630)))

#sy 90-約数      [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 15, 18, 30, 45, 90]
#sy 90-素因数分解 {2: 1, 3: 2, 5: 1}
#my 90-約数      [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 15, 18, 30, 45, 90]

#630は、間違っています。
#sy630-約数      [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 14, 15, 18, 21, 30, 35, 42, 45, 63, 70, 90, 105, 126, 210, 315, 630]
#sy630-素因数分解 {2: 1, 3: 2, 5: 1, 7: 1}
#my630-約数      [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 15, 18, 30, 45, 90]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 問題点① 素因数分解の個数が3個の場合しか対応していません。
> 問題点② リスト内包表記の使い方がわかりませんでした。関数部分1行で書けますか。

※ Python 3.8 以上が必要

```py
from itertools import product
from math import prod
from sympy import factorint, divisors
import sys

def My_SoinsuToYakuSu(factordict):
  return sorted([
    prod([k**v[i] for i, k in enumerate(factordict.keys())])
    for v in product(*map(lambda v: range(v+1), factordict.values()))
  ])

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print("#sy 90-約数     ", divisors(90, generator=False))
  print("#sy 90-素因数分解", factorint(90))
  print("#my 90-約数     ", My_SoinsuToYakuSu(factorint(90)))
  print("")
  print("#sy630-約数     ", divisors(630, generator=False))
  print("#sy630-素因数分解", factorint(630))
  print("#my630-約数     ", My_SoinsuToYakuSu(factorint(630)))

  ## for testing
  print(divisors(sys.maxsize, generator=False) == My_SoinsuToYakuSu(factorint(sys.maxsize)))

=>
#sy 90-約数      [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 15, 18, 30, 45, 90]
#sy 90-素因数分解 {2: 1, 3: 2, 5: 1}
#my 90-約数      [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 15, 18, 30, 45, 90]

#sy630-約数      [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 14, 15, 18, 21, 30, 35, 42, 45, 63, 70, 90, 105, 126, 210, 315, 630]
#sy630-素因数分解 {2: 1, 3: 2, 5: 1, 7: 1}
#my630-約数      [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 14, 15, 18, 21, 30, 35, 42, 45, 63, 70, 90, 105, 126, 210, 315, 630]
True
```

Comment: 個人的にはこちらの方が読みやすく感じます。
> prod([k**v[i] for i, k in enumerate(factordict.keys())])
prod(map(pow, factordict, v))

Answer (score 1):

関数名と変数名を大文字で始めたくはありませんが、提示されている名前をそのまま使用した My_SoinsuToYakuSu のサンプルコードです。
My_factorint は {2: 1, 3: 2, 5: 1} のように素因数分解された辞書の前提です。

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul

def My_SoinsuToYakuSu(My_factorint):
    src = reduce(mul, (k**v for k,v in My_factorint.items()))
    return [i for i in range(1, src+1) if src % i == 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

以下は、今の私の実力です。

```
from sympy import *
import itertools
def My_SoinsuToYakuSuI(My_keys,My_itemsI):
  ans=1
  for v0 in range(len(My_keys)):
      ans=ans*My_keys[v0]**My_itemsI[v0]
  return ans
def My_SoinsuToYakuSu(factordict):
  My_SoinI=[]
  for v0 in factordict.values():
      My_SoinI.append(list(range(v0+1)))
  My_Kumi=My_SoinI[0]
  for v0 in range(1,len(My_SoinI)):
      My_Kumi=[flatten([x, y]) for x in My_Kumi for y in My_SoinI[v0]]
  My_Ans=[]
  for v0 in range(0,len(My_Kumi)):
      My_Ans.append(My_SoinsuToYakuSuI(list(factordict.keys()),My_Kumi[v0]))
  return sorted(My_Ans)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print("# my  90の約数",len(My_SoinsuToYakuSu(factorint( 90))),"個",My_SoinsuToYakuSu(factorint( 90)))
  print("# my 630の約数",len(My_SoinsuToYakuSu(factorint(630))),"個",My_SoinsuToYakuSu(factorint(630)))

# my  90の約数 12 個 [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 15, 18, 30, 45, 90]
# my 630の約数 24 個 [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 14, 15, 18, 21, 30, 35, 42, 45, 63, 70, 90, 105, 126, 210, 315, 630]
```

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=630%E3%81%AE%E7%B4%84%E6%95%B0&lang=ja